filtering a pivoted dataframe
I am trying to filter a pivoted dataframe. But it is giving an error in the pivot part.
How do I fix this?
The executable code is below:
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Year':[2022,2022,2023,2023,2024,2024],
        'Month':[1,12,11,12,1,1],
        'Code':[None,'John Johnson',np.nan,'John Smith','Mary Williams','ted bundy'],
        'Unit Price':[np.nan,200,None,56,75,65],
        'Quantity':[1500, 140000, 1400000, 455, 648, 759],
        'Amount':[100, 10000, 100000, 5, 48, 59],
        'Invoice':['soccer','basketball','baseball','football','baseball','ice hockey'],
        'energy':[100.,100,100,54,98,3],
        'Category':['alpha','bravo','kappa','alpha','bravo','bravo']
})

index_to_use = ['Category','Code','Invoice','Unit Price']
values_to_use = ['Amount','Quantity']
columns_to_use = ['Year','Month']

df2 = df.pivot_table(index=index_to_use,
                            values=values_to_use,
                            columns=columns_to_use)

df3 = df2[df2['Category']=='alpha']



writer= pd.ExcelWriter(
        "t2test2.xlsx",
        engine='xlsxwriter'
    )


df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2",index=True)
df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2test",index=True)
df3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name="t2filter",index=True)

writer.close()


Since you have an index level (and not a column), just use indexing with loc:
df3 = df2.loc[['alpha']]

Output:
                                        Amount           Quantity            
Year                                      2022 2023 2024     2022   2023 2024
Month                                       12   12   1        12     12   1 
Category Code       Invoice  Unit Price                                      
alpha    John Smith football 56.0          NaN  5.0  NaN      NaN  455.0  NaN

If you want to remove the level:
df3 = df2.loc['alpha']

Or with xs:
df3 = df2.xs('alpha', level='Category')

Output:
                               Amount           Quantity            
Year                             2022 2023 2024     2022   2023 2024
Month                              12   12   1        12     12   1 
Code       Invoice  Unit Price                                      
John Smith football 56.0          NaN  5.0  NaN      NaN  455.0  NaN

